# What does names: Set[str] = set() in Python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have code that looks like this:

```
def _check(self) -> None:
    cars = self.cars.all()
    cars.sort(key=self.key)
    names: Set[str] = set()
```

Can someone explain to me what the code `names: Set[str] = set()` is doing?

Comment: It's creating an empty set, and typing `names` as referring to a set of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an initialisation with a [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). It declares that the type of the variable `names` is a set type with string values, which is initialised to an empty set (`= set()`).